# SharePoint installation wrong configuration

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to install all required features for SharePoint 2013 (on Windows Server 2012 R2) and there is problem with Appfabric configuration:

[image]

So I found to use Products Preparation Tool, but I get that kind of exception: 
[image]

Web Server is not properly configuratet, found a method at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fabdulwahab/archive/2013/08/29/sharepoint-2013-installation-and-configuration-issues.aspx but it didn't work. Any idea how to configurate this Web Server that I can finish preparation for SharePoint? I can add that rest of folowing add-ins with whas required to install (screen 1) I have instaled manualy.

Comment: Please provide the log file

Comment: http://1drv.ms/OQDMiL but it is in PL

Comment: http://1drv.ms/OQEOLC EN-US

Comment: Is this what you see when you click on "Review the log file" link?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, Windows Server 2012 R2 is not compatible with SharePoint 2013, it need SharePoint 2013 with service pack 1.